# html cfgrid change the text of Sort Ascending and Sort Descending menu items on column headers

Tags: api, extjs, coldfusion, cfgrid

I am struggling to get this to work and would appreciate any help.
I have a cfgrid which is in html format.
I would like to be able to change the text of the sort menu that appears when you click onto the column heading.
I know there is an ext api that allows you to do alot of changes but I cant seem to put my finger on how to change this text.
There are three texts that need to be changed: Sort Ascending, Sort Descending and Columns.
Please note this grid has to be in the html format and not the applet format where i think you have options to change sorting buttons text.

The reason for changing the text is for my language functionality in the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

many thanks

JC

We are using Coldfusion 9.01
I 'm not sure what code you want to see as all i have is a cfgrid created which wont help really with any answers to my question.

Comment: You did not mention what version of ColdFusion you are running?  Also, how about some code samples?  `cfgridcolumn` allows you to specify column names, if you are using that tag.  Can't tell because there is no code sample.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a way to do this in straight ColdFusion, but if you are using a recent version, you may be able to use JavaScript to handle this for you.

Under the covers, CFGRID is nothing more than EXTJs. WE are able to 'grab' the 'native' JS object that is the grid, and then use this as we would a 'native' EXTJs.

Checkout this link on how to 'grab' the native JS object - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7ff7.html